# ValueError: Unknown type <class 'redis.client.StrictPipeline'>

Tags: python, flask, redis, python-rq

[image]

I develop locally on win10, which is a problem for the usage of the RQ task queue, which only works on linux systems because it requires the ability to fork processes. I'm trying to extend the flask-base project https://github.com/hack4impact/flask-base/tree/master/app which can use RQ. I came across https://github.com/michaelbrooks/rq-win . I love the idea of this repo (If I can get it working it will really simplify my life, since I develop on win 10 -64):

After installing this library

I can queue a job in my views by running something like:

```
     @login_required
     @main.route('/selected')
     def selected():
     messages = 'abcde'
      j = get_queue().enqueue(render_png, messages, result_ttl=5000)
      return j.get_id()
```

This returns a job_code correctly.

I changed the code in manage.py to:

```
from rq_win import WindowsWorker

@manager.command
def run_worker():
    """Initializes a slim rq task queue."""
    listen = ['default']


    REDIS_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
    conn = Redis.from_url(REDIS_URL)

    with Connection(conn):
        # worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker = WindowsWorker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

When I try to run it with:

```
$ python -u manage.py run_worker 


09:40:44
09:40:44 *** Listening on ?[32mdefault?[39;49;00m...
09:40:58 ?[32mdefault?[39;49;00m: ?[34mapp.main.views.render_png('{"abcde"}')?[39;49;00m (8c1b6186-39a5-4daf-9c45-f60e4241cd1f)
...\lib\site-packages\rq\job.py:161: DeprecationWarning: job.status is deprecated. Use job.set_status() instead
  DeprecationWarning
09:40:58 ?[31mValueError: Unknown type <class 'redis.client.StrictPipeline'>?[39;49;00m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\lib\site-packages\rq_win\worker.py", line 87, in perform_job
    queue.enqueue_dependents(job, pipeline=pipeline)
  File "...\lib\site-packages\rq\queue.py", line 322, in enqueue_dependents
    for job_id in pipe.smembers(dependents_key)]
  File "...\lib\site-packages\rq\queue.py", line 322, in <listcomp>
    for job_id in pipe.smembers(dependents_key)]
  File "...\lib\site-packages\rq\compat\__init__.py", line 62, in as_text
    raise ValueError('Unknown type %r' % type(v))
ValueError: Unknown type <class 'redis.client.StrictPipeline'>
```

So in summary, I think the jobs are being queued correctly within redis. However when the worker process tries to grab a job off of the queue to process, This error occurs. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can run it inside the docker container with linux while developing on windows. It would really make the things easier.

Answer (score 3):

So after some digging, it looks like the root of the error is [here](https://github.com/rq/rq/blob/936f2f19f6d850a802e64e9a8efe2ab514a605b3/rq/queue.py#L351), where `job_id` being sent to the `as_text` function is, somehow, a `StrictPipeline` object. However, I have been unable to replicate the error locally; can you post more of your code? Also, I would try re-installing the redis, rq, and rq-win modules, and possibly try importing `rq.compat`

Comment: What would you like to see?